# Is a two dimensional manifold an Euclidean surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is a two-dimensional differentiable manifold an Euclidean surface? I ask this because my professor in graduate school defines a function from the parametrisized manifold to $E^3$( Euclidean space) in order to take the representation $x(u,v)...$Why does he define this function to $E^3$?

Comment: In general no, there are two dimensional manifolds that are not embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. But reallly, you should ask your professor.

Comment: Thank you...therefore i can take the representation x(u,v)=(f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v)) only for an embedded manifold in Euclidean space..Is that right?

Comment: Perhaps your professor specifies the target space to be $E^{3}$ because $E^{3}$ comes equipped with a metric, which an immersed surface "inherits" by restriction/pullback. (By contrast, if we're splitting hairs, _Cartesian space_ $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ comes equipped only with a preferred coordinate system.) The term "Euclidean surface" is not universal, however; it could well mean a flat surface (Gaussian curvature zero), or a complete, simply-connected flat surface, for example.

Comment: Ok thank you...do you mean that the two dimensional manifold is a subset of topological space R^3?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to understand your question (and previous comment). Given a two-dimensional differentiable manifold $M$, there's no "natural" representation in Euclidean/Cartesian space. When you ask "Why does he define this function...", do you mean: 1. Why is he mapping $M$ to $E^{3}$ (instead of some other space)? 2. Why can he assume a mapping from $M$ to $E^{3}$ exists? 3. What technical or pedagogical goal does a mapping from $M$ to $E^{3}$ serve? 4. Something else? And then, to connect the question with the title, what's your definition of _Euclidean surface_? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

From [Wiki: Hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry):

> Hyperbolic plane geometry is also the geometry of saddle surface or pseudospherical surfaces, surfaces with a constant negative Gaussian curvature.